# External html, for headers/navs?

Tags: html, file, header, external

Hey all, looking to see if theres a way to easily include external html file inside the body to repeat on every page, for instance: a navigator or something.

Basically if i have to add a menu item or something, i have to go and paste all the code into each page. Or even a way to section parts off in Dreamweaver to update based on a file or something would work i suppose

Ive done it before through JavaScript with document.writes and stuff, but it was very annoying, and probably a terrible way to go about doing so.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Most html editors have the concept of templates, where you have a fixed
  page with navigation and footer
  areas, and you specify the content
  for each page. THe tool will keep the
  rest in sync.  Look for something
  like this.
- IFrame: Don't do that
- Javascript, like you already talked about.
- Lightweight server side code, like php

I wrote up a post on doing [something like that in php](http://hoolihan.net/blog-tim/?p=48)

Answer (score 0):

That kind of manipulation is generally done **using a programming-language on the server-side** *(Like PHP, for example)*, that can manipulate files *(and other data)* to generate an HTML output.

That way, the HTML output sent to the browser can be built from several distinct files *(header, content, footer, ...)*.

Of course, this means not creating the full-pages as HTML files, and, probably, not seing the full page in your editor... But it brings you a lot of power : it allows you to generate pages dynamically, with dynamic content, interacting with a database, external services, ...

Answer (score 0):

If the external page is local on the web server & you don't use a server side scripting language you can get the web server itself to include content using [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).